# How to bulk print hundreds of tabs (either firefox, chrome, or IE) into PDF

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, pdf, batch, print-to-pdf

I'm trying to print upwards of 250 different Firefox tabs each into an individual PDF file. Alternatively, if this can't be done, what about printing all the tabs into a single PDF file?

Does anyone have any tools or ideas on how this can be done?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Tools like `stapler` would allow you to easily merge several pdf files into one, so you would "only" need to print into pdf that page for each of the 250 tabs.

Comment: True, but what I'm looking for is a tool that would do it automatically, without me having to go through and manually click through each individual print box. Thanks for the input